# Async / Await in simple JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, async-await

My problem is the idea of writing `async / await` in a simple JS file.

I want to implement `react-native-languages` in my app, as the example shows, so I have to create a i18n file in which I set the configuration, which is working as expected. One problem is I want to provide the ability for the user to change the language and when they do I want to store the selected language in my localStorage, so typically I have to check in the i18n file for the localStorage if there is a language or not but as we all know the localStorage is async so how may I do that?

Here is my i18n file

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import RNLanguages from 'react-native-languages';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

import en from '@languages/en.json';
import ar from '@languages/ar.json';

let default_language = async () => {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
}

// the above approach is not working

i18n.locale = RNLanguages.language;
i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { ar, en }

export default i18n;
```

How can make the code wait for the fetch in the local storage before executing anything else ?

Comment: `await default_language()`?

Comment: That's the best i thought of 

Comment: Your `aync` function is equal to write: `let default_language = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('language')`. The only thing your function does it waits for the result of `AsyncStorage.getItem('language')` to wrap that result into a promise again.

Answer (score -1):

Asynchronous functions are asynchronous.

You cannot make an asynchronous function run synchronously.

You can create the *illusion* of running an asynchronous function run synchronously by using the `await` keyword inside a function which is marked with the `async` keyword.

You can only `await` a value that is a Promise. (I have no idea if `AsyncStorage.getItem('language')` returns a Promise or not).

To make this work, the `async` function will **always return a Promise**.

So:

> ```
> let default_language = async () => {
>   return await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
> }
> ```

Creates a function, which is assigned to `default_language`.

That function will return a promise. That promise will resolve to the value you are returning. Since that needs to be a Promise, that value will be a Promise. If you resolve a promise with another promise, it adopts the new promise.

This means your code is functionally the same as:

```
let default_language = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
```

Wrapping the extra function around it is more-or-less pointless. It just makes a slightly shorter name to call later on.

It is only useful to use `async` / `await` if you are going to do something with the value *inside* the `async` function:

```
let default_language = async () => {
  const lang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
  console.log(lang);
  something_useful(lang);
  return lang;
}
```

Comment: does that mean that there is no way for me to assign the `default_language` to the result of `AsyncStorage` ? all i want to do is to fetch the local storage using `AsyncStorage` and return the value to detect if the user has a preferred language or not, before executing the next line

Comment: Yes. You cannot make an asynchronous function run synchronously.

Comment: @Quentin wouldn't he be able to pause the execution of the outer function, by awaiting the promise to resolve, essentially giving him what he wants in the first place? I just am at a loss on how to `extract` the value of a Promise after it has resolved, because await would prevent extraction beforehand

Comment: @Dellirium — "wouldn't he be able to pause the execution of the outer function" — No. It isn't `async`. (Unless you mean the `default_language` function, which I demonstrated in the last code example in this answer, but they want to use it after calling that function, not inside that function).

Comment: @Dellirium — "I just am at a loss on how to extract the value of a Promise after it has resolved" — You can't.

Comment: @Quentin I mean't to turn it async, since this is the execution he wants to stop, essentially. And to further expand on the "you can't". What is the point then, how do we use the value, rather then the promise.

Comment: @Dellirium — "I mean't to turn it async" - It's the top level of the module, not a function, so you can't.

Comment: @Dellirium — "What is the point then, how do we use the value, rather then the promise." — The point is that you design your code to work asynchronously, and get nicer syntax when you want to deal with multiple async calls (by putting them in an async function and using await).

Answer (score -1):

You would like to use `defaultLanguage` when it resolved. The `await` expression causes async function execution to pause until a promise is resolved. When you call `setLanguage` function, it will wait until `defaultLanguage` resolved or rejected. Rather than to use `async`, you can first look at how to use a callback function. I believe it more useful to understand how `async` works.

```
let setLanguage = async () => {
   // you may add get keyword to function name
   let defaultLanguage = await default_language();
   // check defaultLanguage and set if necessary
}
```

Comment: how would that work exactly ? i'm not getting your example

Comment: You would like to use defaultLanguage when it resolved. The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is resolved. When you call setLanguage function, it will wait until defaultLanguage resolved or rejected. Rather than to use async, you can first look at how to use a callback function. I believe it more useful to understand how async works.

Comment: Consider moving your explanation up into the answer itself so others won't have to look in the comments.